# Magnetic field outside permanent magnet

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

Magnetic field outside permanent magnet after field lines are contained in iron core.So there is no field outside a magnet. Then how external magnet will interact with enclosed magnetic field
can same polarity magnet repel or attract .[image]

Comment: Can you edit your question to clarify what you are asking

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are asking with this question. I think that you are asking what would a magnet do if it is near other magnets that are between 2 blocks of steel that are taking the magnetic field from the magnets that are attached to it.

In the image that you have shared the end blocks would be steel and would re-direct most of the magnetic field from the magnets that are between them. This magnetic field that is flowing through them would make these steel blocks act like a magnet. A good example of this is the blog post from K&J Magnetics, [Does Steel Block or Improve Magnetic Strength](https://www.kjmagnetics.com/blog.asp?p=block-or-extend). The paperclips that are stuck to the magnet in the first part of the post become a magnet and can attract other ferrous materials.

The external magnet in your scenario would be attracted to the opposite poles of the magnets in the steel blocks or it would be attracted to the opposite pole of the magnetic field induced in the steel blocks.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but i was thinking magnetic direction inside and outside are different.so that's why i was asking if magnet will act differently in this arrangement?